# TSQL Merge error handling

Tags: t-sql, error-handling, merge

Need help handling  errors while running a merge statement.
How do I make the merge behave as if it has  a try-catch block surrounding each row processed
( If an error is encountered, catch that error and log it (or any other processing)  then continue processing the next rows)?
What is the default behavior of the Merge statement, does it rollback the whole transaction when an error occurs or it continues processing the records?
Can the  output clause be used to check for errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MERGE, as with all other DML statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) is an all or nothing proposition - either it succeeds in it's entirety, or it fails (and the implicit transaction it's running within, if such a one has been opened, is rolled back).

If there are going to be actual errors (e.g. broken foreign key constraints, check constraints, truncation), you need to deal with these beforehand, or alter your MERGE so that the error will not occur (e.g. explicitly truncate overlong data). If the source of your MERGE statement is a complex query, and the data cleanup is likely to be complex, you might want to stage the results into a temporary table to perform such cleanup.

Comment: Since my data is in a staging table I'll try dealing with these problems before running the merge. Any where I can find a list of these type of errors so I can pre check it?

Comment: @Debra - the usual types of errors you'll encounter will be specific to the table you're targetting - as I say, it'll be problems with constraints on the table (PK, FK, Check, Unique), or data type issues (trying to put alpha characters into a numeric column, or text that's longer than a column allows).

Comment: In addition to the list of things that @Damien_The_Unbeliever says check table triggers to see if there are some constraints in a trigger that need to be checked for.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that you should check for required values, if a field does not allow nulls, then you need to check the data to ensure it will not have nulls for that field.