# Determine which records errored during an ExecuteNonQuery action

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2008, merge

I am attempting to perform a mass "upsert" in a SQL Server 2008 database by using a temporary table and a `MERGE` command. First, I am loading all the data from a list object into a `DataTable`. I then create a temp table in the SQL database, load the data in that table, and then call `MERGE` on the temp table and the target table.

I'm using the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method of a `SqlCommand` object to call the `MERGE`. The problem is, this will only tell me the total amount of records added but will not specify which ones.

Is there a method or technique where I can programmatically determine which records erred during the transaction? Below is the method I'm using.

```
    private static string insertCommand =
        "INSERT (ChannelCode, DrmTerrDesc, IndDistrnId, StateCode, ZipCode, EndDate, EffectiveDate, LastUpdateId, LastUpdateDate, ErrorCodes, Status) " +
        "VALUES(Source.ChannelCode, Source.DrmTerrDesc, Source.IndDistrnId, Source.StateCode, Source.ZipCode, Source.EndDate, Source.EffectiveDate, Source.LastUpdateId, Source.LastUpdateDate, Source.ErrorCOdes, Source.Status)";

    private static string updateCommand = "UPDATE SET Target.ChannelCode = Source.ChannelCode, Target.DrmTerrDesc = Source.DrmTerrDesc, Target.IndDistrnId = Source.IndDistrnId," +
                                                "Target.StateCode = Source.StateCode, Target.ZipCode = Source.ZipCode, Target.EndDate = Source.EndDate, Target.EffectiveDate = Source.EffectiveDate," +
                                                "Target.LastUpdateId = Source.LastUpdateId, Target.LastUpdateDate = Source.LastUpdateDate, Target.ErrorCodes = Source.ErrorCodes," +
                                                "Target.Status = Source.Status ";

    public static void Update(List<ZipCodeTerritory> updates, Dictionary<ZipCodeTerritory, string> errorList)
    {
        try
        {
            //Load updates into datatable
            DataTable table = LoadData(updates, true);

            //Script to create temp table
            string tmpTable =   "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZipCodeTerritoryTemp]( " +
                                "[ChannelCode] [char](1) NOT NULL, " +
                                "[DrmTerrDesc] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL, " +
                                "[IndDistrnId] [char](3) NULL, " +
                                "[StateCode] [char](3) NOT NULL, " +
                                "[ZipCode] [char](9) NULL, " +
                                "[EndDate] [date] NOT NULL, " +
                                "[EffectiveDate] [date] NOT NULL, " +
                                "[LastUpdateId] [char](8) NULL, " +
                                "[LastUpdateDate] [date] NULL, " +
                                "[Id] [int] NULL, " +               
                                "[ErrorCodes] [varchar](255) NULL, " +
                                "[Status] [char](1) NULL)";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                //Create temp table
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(tmpTable, connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                try
                {

                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                    {
                        //Write to temp table
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ZipCodeTerritoryTemp";
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);

                        //Merge changes in temp table with ZipCodeTerritory
                        string mergeSql = "merge ZipCodeTerritory as Target " +
                                          "using ZipCodeTerritoryTemp as Source " +
                                          "on " +
                                          "Target.Id = Source.Id " +
                                          "when matched then " +
                                          updateCommand +
                                          "when not matched then " +
                                          insertCommand + ";";

                        cmd.CommandText = mergeSql;
                        int results = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    //Drop temp table
                    SqlCommand final = new SqlCommand("DROP TABLE [dbo].[ZipCodeTerritoryTemp]", connection);
                    final.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Couldn't you create a stored-procedure for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TSQL Merge error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067441/tsql-merge-error-handling)